# Error Saving File in Document Folder of Library

Tags: vbscript, hta

I am writing an HTA file with VBScript as the scripting language. I have a function where the user is prompted to choose the folder in which they would like to save a document. I didn't write this code myself, but instead borrowed it from [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_ui_selectfolder.php).

```
Function SelectFolder(myStartFolder)
Dim objFolder, objItem, objShell

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select Folder to Save New File", 0, myStartFolder)

If IsObject(objFolder) Then SelectFolder = objFolder.Self.Path
End Function
```

I call this function in another one in order when I make the file and prompt the user to choose where to save it:

```
Sub Example()
Dim destPath, destFile, objWorkbook
destPath = SelectFolder(libPath)
destPath = destPath & "\Sample Export"

Set destFile = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = destFile.Workbooks.Add()
objWorkbook.SaveAs(destPath)

(code to edit excel file)

End Sub
```

Example() works fine except when someone chooses to save their document in one of the four default libraries in Windows (Documents, Music, Pictures, Videos). In that case, I receive an error saying "The file could not be accessed" and indicating the error is at the line that says "objWorkbook.SaveAs(destPath)". The error box then gives me the following suggestions:

- Make sure the specified folder exists
- Make sure the folder that contains the file is not read-only
- Make sure the file name does not contain any of the following characters: < > ? { } : | or *
- Make sure the file/path name doesn't contain more than 218 characters.

The error occurs when I open the HTA file and click a button calling Example(), which then opens a dialog box to ask the user to choose the file location. When Documents, Music, Pictures, or Videos is chosen, a "Script Error" box pops up with the error message listed above. I am not familiar enough with VBScript to know what the problem is exactly. I would appreciate any suggestions as to what to do.

Comment: Please read carefully ==> [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
==> [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
==> [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
===> [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: ^... + files and folders in the question are messed up. Please elaborate your question, and add the relevant code to the question too.

Comment: You haven't shown your code. Is the Dialog returning an error? If so, what error?  or Is the error in the next line, after the dialog has returned a reference to a system virtual folder which only works with shell commands, not file commands?

Comment: I have added code and elaborated on the error. Apologies for the lack of information in the initial question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what the solution to the above issue was. However, I noticed that the path I pass to `SelectFolder` had a typo in it. `libPath` was supposed to be to the `%userprofile%` from the environment variable. However, I had pluralized "userprofiles" so that it was `%userprofiles%` instead. This took me to somewhere that looked right but wasn't. I fixed the typo and now `BrowseForFolder` takes me to `C:/Users/*username*` like it's supposed to. It turns out that I was being sent to the Desktop location because of the fourth argument in `BrowseForFolder`, instead of the user profile like I wanted.